# How to decode JSON with type convert from string to float64

Tags: json, go

I need to decode a JSON string with the float number like:

```
{"name":"Galaxy Nexus", "price":"3460.00"}
```

I use the Golang code below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Product struct {
    Name  string
    Price float64
}

func main() {
    s := `{"name":"Galaxy Nexus", "price":"3460.00"}`
    var pro Product
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &pro)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pro)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pro)
    }
}
```

When I run it, get the result:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type float64
{Name:Galaxy Nexus Price:0}
```

I want to know how to decode the JSON string with type convert.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

The answer is considerably less complicated.  Just add tell the JSON interpeter it's a string encoded float64 with `,string` (note that I only changed the `Price` definition):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Product struct {
    Name  string
    Price float64 `json:",string"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{"name":"Galaxy Nexus", "price":"3460.00"}`
    var pro Product
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &pro)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pro)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pro)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the best solution for my problem. Could you tell me where is the official document about the usage of ",string"?

Comment: Note that the leading comma in front of `json:",string"` is necessary - it won't work without it.

Comment: @dustin any idea how to do that other way around? Convert json number to go string? e.g. `"N": 1234` to `N: "1234"`?

Comment: That's really awesome. Except it doesn't work on slices. Does anyone know a way how to do this for []int ? Simply adding the ",string" flag produces: "cannot unmarshal string into go value of int" (http://play.golang.org/p/aFWSH4lUxv)

Comment: @KamilDziedzic did you get a solution of your query?

Comment: Official document: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal `The "string" option signals that a field is stored as JSON inside a JSON-encoded string. It applies only to fields of string, floating point, integer, or boolean types. This extra level of encoding is sometimes used when communicating with JavaScript programs`

Comment: Does anybody know how to accept both number and string?

Comment: When serializing a float with 0 decimals, eg 123.00,  it is serialized as `"field": "123"` without any decimals. Is there a way for me to always include 2 decimals?

Comment: sounds interesting, do you think it works from int to string ?  I tried this https://go.dev/play/p/wLNA1Zu0CAU, but it returns **json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Product.Price of type string**

Answer (score 21):

Just letting you know that you can do this without `Unmarshal` and use `json.decode`. Here is [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qnjfVVcYYZ)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Product struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Price float64 `json:"price,string"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{"name":"Galaxy Nexus","price":"3460.00"}`
    var pro Product
    err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(s)).Decode(&pro)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(pro)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the reverser? i.e decode a number into a string variable?

Comment: @theNoble247 did you find a solution for it? ( reverser)

Answer (score 6):

Avoid converting a string to []byte: `b := []byte(s)`. It allocates a new memory space and copy the whole the content into it.

`strings.NewReader` interface is better. Below is the code from godoc:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    const jsonStream = `
    {"Name": "Ed", "Text": "Knock knock."}
    {"Name": "Sam", "Text": "Who's there?"}
    {"Name": "Ed", "Text": "Go fmt."}
    {"Name": "Sam", "Text": "Go fmt who?"}
    {"Name": "Ed", "Text": "Go fmt yourself!"}
`
    type Message struct {
        Name, Text string
    }
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonStream))
    for {
        var m Message
        if err := dec.Decode(&m); err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", m.Name, m.Text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes a great point that I quoted. Did I add to it? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546

Answer (score 4):

Passing a value in quotation marks make that look like string. Change `"price":"3460.00"` to `"price":3460.00` and everything works fine.

If you can't drop the quotations marks you have to parse it by yourself, using `strconv.ParseFloat`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type Product struct {
    Name       string
    Price      string
    PriceFloat float64
}

func main() {
    s := `{"name":"Galaxy Nexus", "price":"3460.00"}`
    var pro Product
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &pro)
    if err == nil {
        pro.PriceFloat, err = strconv.ParseFloat(pro.Price, 64)
        if err != nil { fmt.Println(err) }
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pro)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pro)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way that not changing the 'Product' struct and implement a decode function or interface to parse the string to float?

Comment: @yanunon Yes, you can use a map of type `map[string]interface{}` for `Unmarshal`, and parse that into your struct.

Comment: @yanunon Or if you want **real** flexibility, you can write your own `Unmarshal`, which calls default `Unmarshal` with a  `map[string]interface{}`, but uses `reflect` and `strconv` packages to do the parsing.