# How do I unmarshal a string value from a JSON document into a variable of type int?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

My struct:

```
type User struct {
    FirstName     string `json:"firstname, omitempty" validate:"required"` 
    LastName      string `json:"lastname, omitempty" validate:"required"`
    NumberofDays  int   `json:"numberofdays, string" validate:"min=0,max=100"`
}
```

Value for NumberofDays is passed as string from the server but I want to check if it is within range and store as int.

Ex: `user := &User{"Michael","Msk","3"}`

I'm getting 'cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int'.

I'm not sure how to typecast to int and do the validation

Comment: You've defined NumberofDays as a type of string in the struct tag, you can only use the validate flag with an int type. So change string to int and pass in 3 and not "3"

Comment: See examples https://goplay.space/#l0bNArNn14

Comment: @reticentroot All values are passed from server as string. I cannot change that.

Comment: see the example I provided. I also provided an alternative that uses "3". You may not control the values, but you can definitely change your struct

Comment: According to the question they're trying to *un*marshal, not marshal, but maybe OP can clarify.

Comment: You will have to do some programming. There is no magical unmarshal-typeconvert-validate-whatnotall syntactic sugar syntax for such things. I know programming is awful, but sometimes necessary.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452897/how-to-decode-json-with-type-convert-from-string-to-float64-in-golang

Answer (score 4):

Remove the space after the comma in the struct tags, e.g. `json:"numberofdays, string"` should be `json:"numberofdays,string"`. With the space, the `json` package ignores the `string` part, hence the error message you're getting. Without the space, the error goes away and behavior is as expected.

Demo comparing the two here: https://play.golang.org/p/AUImnw_PIS

Documentation of `json` package struct tags: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Comment: Define "it's not working"? The error you quoted in the question is fixed by changing the code quoted in the question as indicated in the answer. What is the issue you have after applying that fix?

Comment: Error message is : 'cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int'

Comment: Then double-check your struct tags. With the correct struct tags as indicated in this answer, you should not be getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom type to unmarshal a string
to an integer value using whatever set of parsing rules
you want this mapping to use:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type User struct {
    FirstName    string `json:"firstname,omitempty" validate:"required"`
    LastName     string `json:"lastname,omitempty" validate:"required"`
    NumberofDays StrInt `json:"numberofdays" validate:"min=0,max=100"`
}

type StrInt int

func (si *StrInt) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var s string
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    n, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *si = StrInt(n)
    return nil
}

const data = `{
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "NumberOfDays": "42"
}`

func main() {
    var u User
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &u)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ma5ubkVANj).

The idea is as follows:

1. Have a custom type which is mostly `int` but allows defining custom methods on it.
2. Have that type satisfy the `encoding/json.Unmarshaler` interface by implementing the `UnmarshalJSON()` method on a pointer to that type.
3. In the method, first unmarshal the value as its native type—`string`—and
   then *parse* it as an integer.

This approach might appear to be weird, but if you'll think of it
a bit more, there's no single "true" string representation of an integer:
there are different bases and different conventions at representing
integers even in a particular base.

In your unmarshaling method you implement the policy of the text representation
of your integers.

Comment: The struct tags in your example code are invalid. A space after the comma in the struct tag causes everything after the comma to be ignored by the `json` package. A custom type and unmarshaller *is not necessary in this case*.

Comment: @Adrian, could you please cite the relevant bit of documentation regarding the mapping of types via the field tags?

Comment: Already linked from my answer. It's documented on `json.Marshal` and demonstrated in the playground example linked from my answer.

Comment: @Adrian, found it now, thanks. Since my answer is still technically correct, I've updated its wording to not be misleading. BTW it's interesting that the doc is silent on what exactly the rules of interpreting those strings are. It's a bit useless IMO w/o strict specification of the behaviour.

Comment: @Adrian, and yes, it appears, "0xff" is not a valid integer string representation for the unmarshaling rules implemented by that `,string` tag option—[an example](https://play.golang.org/p/bU7-mYZgfd).

Comment: OK, but that doesn't seem relevant to this question.

Comment: @Adrian, I don't quite understand why are you so picky about my answer. You like your solution better? Okay, that's perfectly fine! So what? My solution also addresses the request to perform what the OP called "type casting while unmarshaling". Your solution is simpler, mine is more flexible—when needed. The OP now has access to the full range of tools to attack their problem.

Answer (score 0):

The json package defines a custom type `json.Number` for these cases.