# Decode JSON value which can be either string or number

Tags: json, go

When I make an HTTP call to a REST API I may get the JSON value `count` back as a Number or String. I'ld like to marshal it to be an integer in either case. How can I deal with this in Go?.

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47206552/720999).

Comment: Do you need to be able to marshal it or unmarshal it? Or both?

Comment: Unmarshal. JSON -> Object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the "string" field tag option to specify that strings should be converted to numbers. The  [documentation](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshal) for the option is:

> The "string" option signals that a field is stored as JSON inside a JSON-encoded string. It applies only to fields of string, floating point, integer, or boolean types. This extra level of encoding is sometimes used when communicating with JavaScript programs:

Here's an example use:

```
type S struct {
    Count int `json:"count,string"`
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/qpFGVgcSXm)

If the JSON value can be number or string, then unmarshal to interface{} and convert to int after unmarshaling:

```
Count interface{} `json:"count,string"`
```

Use this function to convert the interface{} value to an int:

```
func getInt(v interface{}) (int, error) {
  switch v := v.(type) {
  case float64:
    return int(v), nil
  case string:
    c, err := strconv.Atoi(v)
    if err != nil {
       return 0, err
    }
    return c, nil
  default:
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("conversion to int from %T not supported", v)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is better if you always want to use string in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Format of your expected request
type request struct {
    ACTIVE    string `json:"active"`
    CATEGORY  string `json:"category"`
}

// struct to read JSON input
var myReq request 

// Decode the received JSON request to struct
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
err := decoder.Decode(&myReq)
  if err != nil {
  log.Println( err)
// Handler for invalid JSON received or if you want to decode the request using another struct with int.
  return
}
defer r.Body.Close()

// Convert string to int
numActive, err = strconv.Atoi(myReq.ACTIVE)
if err != nil {
  log.Println(err) 
// Handler for invalid int received
  return
}

// Convert string to int    
numCategory, err = strconv.Atoi(myReq.CATEGORY)
if err != nil {
  log.Println(err)
// Handler for invalid int received
  return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a list of values where the values were string or struct. The solution I'm using is to create a helper struct with fields of expected types and parse value into the correct field.

```
type Flag struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}

type FlagOrString struct {
    Flag   *Flag
    String *string
}

func (f *FlagOrString) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    start := []byte("\"")
    for idx := range start {
        if b[idx] != start[idx] {
            return json.Unmarshal(b, &f.Flag)
        }
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &f.String)
}

var MainStruct struct {
    Vals []FlagOrString
}
```

Custom `Unmarshaller` simplifies a code. Personally I prefer this over `interface{}` as it explicitly states what a developer expects.

Answer (score 0):

go standard lib "json/encoding" offers a `json.Number` type for parsing both string number and integers in JSON data.

Here's an example use:

```
type Foo struct {
    Value json.Number `json:"value"`
}
```

`json.Number` is actually an alias for `string`, `json.Unmarshal` handles it specially during unmarshalling to support both formats, like "123" and 123.

Once you have a `json.Number`, you can extract its numerical representation using the methods `.Int64()` or `.Float64()` according to the need.

[playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/ckDB9tOmvGq):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    Value json.Number `json:"value"`
}

func main() {
    // json int -> json.Number
    var foo Foo
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"value": 123}`), &foo); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("json unmarshal err:", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("foo: %+v\n", foo)

    // json string -> json.Number
    var foo2 Foo
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"value": "123"}`), &foo2); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("json unmarshal err:", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("foo2: %+v\n", foo2)

    // json.Number -> int64
    intValue, err := foo.Value.Int64()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("value.Int64() err:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("intValue:", intValue)
}
```

output:

```
foo: {Value:123}
foo2: {Value:123}
intValue: 123
```