# Go Convert type when marshaling to json

Tags: json, mongodb, go, marshalling

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452897/how-to-decode-json-with-type-convert-from-string-to-float64-in-golang), however instead of converting a `float64` to a `string` which is handled using the [string tag](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).  In my case I'm trying to convert a [`ObjectID`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/objectid#ObjectID) to a string using it's [`.Hex()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/objectid#ObjectID.Hex) method.  And, vice versa using the [`.FromHex()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/objectid#FromHex) function on the way back.

However, more generically how do I convert from type `X` to type `Y` & back during the `Marshal` & `Unmarshal`ing?

My Example:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/objectid"
)

type Greeting struct {
    Id          *objectid.ObjectID  `json:"id"`
    Greeting    string              `json:"greeting,omitempty"`
}


func main() {
    // Create ObjectID
    id, err := objectid.FromHex("5b14dd20f6418c8443a5ffec")
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    // Create Greeting
    g := Greeting{&id, "Hello, World!"}

    // Marshal to json
    j, err := json.Marshal(g)
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    // Print Json
    fmt.Printf("Json: %s", string(j))

}
```

Output:

```
Json: {"id":[91,20,221,32,246,65,140,132,67,165,255,236],"greeting":"Hello, World!"}
```

Whereas, what I'd like is:

```
Json: {"id":"5b14dd20f6418c8443a5ffec","greeting":"Hello, World!"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write your own (un)marshalling function in which you process your conversions/conditions and handle it as argument in calling the json (un)marshalling.

```
type Whatever struct {
   someField int
}

func (w Whatever) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(struct{
        SomeField int `json:"some_field"`
    }{
        SomeField: w.someField,
    })
}

func (w Whatever) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
   return json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
       "some_field": w.SomeField,
   })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a named type to `objectid.ObjectId` that would implement the `json.Marshaler` interface to override the standard marshaling and output the hex  string instead:

```
type Id objectid.ObjectId

func (id Id) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(objectid.ObjectId(id).Hex())
}
```

And use it instead of `objectid.ObjectId` in your structs:

```
type Greeting struct {
    Id Id
    Greeting string
}
```

Now, as you marshal a `Greeting`, the json package would marshal the `Greeting` field as expected, but the since the `Id` field implements `json.Marshaler`, it would be marshaled by `Id.MarshalJSON` which would output `id.Hex()`.

You can do the same for unmarshaling by implementing the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface for `Id`.

Comment: I'm using the same struct to retrieve data from MongoDB, so I don't really have control over the types in the struct.  (Or at least, I'd have to deal with this same issue from the other end)

Comment: This is **not** an alias! `Id`is just a named type with `objectid.ObjectId`being the underlying type. This is not aliasing!

Comment: @Volker Thanks, fixed.