# how do i enforce the proper data types on gofiber golang from POST data from frontend?

Tags: reactjs, go, types, go-fiber

I am receiving the following POST request json data from react frontend

```
{
    "field_one": "first",
    "field_two": "second",
    "field_three": "3.00"
}
```

but i want golang to convert it to this before processing the request

```
{
    "field_one": "first",
    "field_two": "second",
    "field_three": 3.00
}
```

I want to convert the `field_three` from string to **float64**, but i am unable to have golang accept the string and process the proper data type

here is my golang function processing the POST request data

```
func PostCreate(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    
    type PostCreateData struct {
        fieldOne       string  `json:"field_one" form:"field_one" validate:"required"`
        fieldTwo       string  `json:"field_two" form:"field_two" validate:"required"`
        fieldThree     float64 `json:"field_three" form:"field_three" validate:"required"`
    }

    data := PostCreateCreateData{}

    if err := c.BodyParser(&data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    validate := validator.New()
        if err := validate.Struct(data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    postCreate := models.PostCreate{
        fieldOne:         data.fieldOne,
        fieldTwo:         data.fieldTwo,
        fieldThree:       float64(data.fieldThree),
    }

    database.DB.Create(&postCreate)
    return c.JSON(postCreate)
}
```

Currently the request is not getting processed because the wrong data type for `field_three` which is supposed to be **float64** but frontend is sending everything as string

What steps am i missing here?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452897/how-to-decode-json-with-type-convert-from-string-to-float64) help?

Comment: what will be in `a` and `b`? in `err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(a), b) ` am thinking `b` will be `&data` but what will be in `a` and what line position do i place the line of code?

Answer (score 1):

fixed by updating the function to this

```
func PostCreate(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    
    type PostCreateData struct {
        fieldOne       string  `json:"field_one" form:"field_one" validate:"required"`
        fieldTwo       string  `json:"field_two" form:"field_two" validate:"required"`
        fieldThree     float64 `json:"field_three,string" form:"field_three" validate:"required"`
    }

    data := PostCreateCreateData{}

    if err := c.BodyParser(&data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    validate := validator.New()
        if err := validate.Struct(data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    postCreate := models.PostCreate{
        fieldOne:         data.fieldOne,
        fieldTwo:         data.fieldTwo,
        fieldThree:       float64(data.fieldThree),
    }

    database.DB.Create(&postCreate)
    return c.JSON(postCreate)
}
```

so updated the struct to expect string in the body

```
fieldThree     float64 `json:"field_three,string" form:"field_three" validate:"required"`
```

and works like a charm!!!